# unknown files suddenly eats free space in my computer

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

My problem was when I checked the space of my drive C:, I know it has at least 50Gb of free space before, and now it has only 25Gb of free space.
so I check the folders that eat a lot of space. I found this:

C:\Users\Yuann\AppData\Local
it has 23.2Gb

but it was weird that when I selected all the files and go to their properties, the results are kinda weird:

834Mb

the hidden files are shown and also selected.

I also run Ace Utilities : Remove Junk files

Help guys, i need to retrieve the free space, advance thank you.

Comment: Have you also enabled showing system/operating system files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run [TreeSizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) (as admin) and look which files use most space in this folder:

[image]

Comment: alright, so I run as admin that program, i found out that there is a folder that I can't see by using explorer

Comment: https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/969018_599365693415197_730605319_n.jpg

Comment: Those folders  under "rotinom" are my files that I copied from G: to E: four days ago I think and why those files and folders exist in that weird folder? :D Should I delete it? I already have those files copied to E:

Comment: google shows virus information when I search for rotinom. Is this a tool you used to copy the files?

Comment: I deleted it, and I recovered the space. my C: now have 48Gb free space, cheers magicandre1981, thank you very much :D

Comment: ok. I also use this tool all the time when I want to know which files/folders use most HDD space. Mark the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I think my usb (G:) have viruses in it because its from another pc, and a week ago my Kaspersky Anti Virus just expired... I can't scan my usb and I really need to transfer the files under G: to E: ...so I take the risk hahaha, anyway, I need new anti-virus, any recommendation?

Comment: I'm new here, how do I mark the answer? :D

Comment: oh, I think that was the check mark haha, Thanks :D

Comment: Microsoft Security Essentials?